# Removing information such as soft links from an RPM package on Linux

Tags: linux, rpm

I provide an RPM package that contains both 32-bit and 64-bit applications, and can be installed in either mode, i.e. on both 32-bit and 64-bit platforms.

As the package contains both applications, when trying to install the RPM package on a 32-bit Linux machine it creates soft links for 64-bit applications too, along with the 32-bit application. During post-install I remove the soft-links for the 64-bit application as we cannot install it on a 32-bit machine.

Unfortunately, although the package is already installed on the 32-bit machine, and I have removed the soft links for the 64-bit application as a part of the post-install, the RPM still contains info for these 64-bit application soft links, which can be seen when queried through the `rpm` command but which in reality are not present.

How can I query through `rpm` and remove the extra info for a 64-bit application? This should be done during installation of the 32-bit package, but may be done in post-install.

Comment: Wait, you have one package that provides both archs?

Comment: Yes, one package that can install on both 32-bit and 64-bit linux.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution is to not include the symlinks in the RPM package itself, but to create them as needed by the RPM's post-install script.

i.e. the post-install script should check the host's architecture. if 32-bit then create symlinks for 32-bit (if needed), else if 64-bit then create symlinks for 64-bit.